# How to solve a linear system of the type $AX=C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, physics

In physics, multicomponent-diffusion can be modeled with the following system of equations

$$\sum_j A_{ij}(v_j-v_i)+B_{i}=0 \tag{1}$$.

where $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$, and $0\leq i,j\leq n$. I would like to solve it and find the vector $\mathbf v$.

So I thought this could be rewritten : $(\mathbf V)_{ij}=v_j-v_i$, and then we can rewrite $(1)$ : $(\mathbf A \mathbf V)_{ii} + (\mathbf B)_{ii}=0$. Meaning that we would interpret the $B_i$ as $B_{ii}$, and all the $B_{ij}$ with $i\neq j  $ would be random numbers since they don't enter directly the calculation. We could say to simplify that they are $0$. My idea is to interpret the vector $\mathbf B$ as the diagonal of a matrix $\mathbf B$.

If one could write $\mathbf A \mathbf V + \mathbf B=0$, the game would be almost won, since $\mathbf V +\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf B=0$.

So my questions are : is there a way to extend $(\mathbf A \mathbf V)_{ii} + (\mathbf B)_{ii}=0$ to something like $\mathbf A \mathbf V + \mathbf B=0$ ?
And once  $\mathbf V =-\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf B$, how could I get the $v_i$ ?

**Edit 1 : adding a constraint.**

As noticed in the comments, the system being underdetermined, let's add another constraint : $\sum_i \alpha_i v_i=0$. Or $\sum_{i,j} \beta_i (v_j-v_i)=0$.

**Edit 2 : To be more concret.**

As an example, let's take 3 equations.

$  A_{12}(v_2-v_1)+A_{13}(v_3-v_1)+B_{1}=0 \\A_{12}(v_1-v_2)+A_{23}(v_3-v_2)+B_{2}=0 \\ A_{13}(v_1-v_3)+A_{23}(v_2-v_3)+B_{3}=0  $.

The matrix $\mathbf A= \begin{bmatrix} A_{11} &A_{12}&A_{13}\\A_{12} &A_{22}&A_{23}\\A_{31}&A_{32}&A_{33} \end{bmatrix}$. For simplicity, since the diagonal doesn't appear in the equation, one could choose:  $\mathbf A= \begin{bmatrix}0 &A_{12}&A_{13}\\A_{12} &0&A_{23}\\A_{31}&A_{32}&0 \end{bmatrix}$.

The matrix $\mathbf B=\begin{bmatrix} B_{1}&0&0 \\0&B_{2}&0\\0&0&B_3 \end{bmatrix}$, if we replace all the non diagonal term by $0$.

And the matrix $\mathbf V=\begin{bmatrix} 0&v_1-v_2&v_1-v_3 \\v_2-v_1&0&v_2-v_3\\v_3-v_1&v_3-v_2&0 \end{bmatrix}$.

This case with only three equations can be solved by hand. What's more intersting are the cases with a lot of components. There, having a generalized formula can be convenient.

Comment: The system is at least once undetermined. You can add an arbitrary constant to every $v_i$.

Comment: Isn't $B$ a vector? So why do you write $B_{ii}$?

Comment: Please give information about the indexes $i,j$.  What are their ranges?

Comment: If you are still interested in help from Readers, I suggest giving a small example, e.g. $3\times 3$, to clarify your notation.  The outstanding issues are most significantly whether $B$ is a (column?) vector rather than a matrix, and what relationship the ranges of $i$ and $j$ have (my suspicion is they share a range, but it is worth stating in the body of your Question).

Comment: @hardmath I tried to fix it and to be clearer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I added a constraint

Comment: @mimuller I tried to clarify that point

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a vector $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n$ of unknowns to be determined. Suppose we are interested in $m$ differences of unknowns. Introducing a signed [incidence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) $\mathrm C \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, the vector of differences is $\rm C x$. Suppose now that we have $m$ linear equations in these $m$ differences. Hence, we have

$$\rm A C x = b$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ and $\mathrm b \in \mathbb R^m$. Note that $\mathrm C 1_n = 0_m$, which is why electrical circuits have a ground node.

Suppose $m = n-1$. Hence, matrix $\rm A C$ is fat and the linear system is *underdetermined*. Given that there are infinitely many solutions, we can consider a special one, such as the **least-norm** solution

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|\mathrm x\|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm C \mathrm x = \mathrm b\end{array}$$

Comment: Thx. The number of differences is m=n-1. For example, if n=3, so we are intersted in $v_3-v_2$ and $v_3-v_1$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean in the first question, I'm not sure about the definition of a graph. $\mathbf A$ is symmetric. And I think one can assume its diagonal has any values. I don't know much more.

Comment: What can you tell about the graph? Do you know the rank of $A$? Note that my $A$ and your $A$ may not be the same.

Comment: I updated my answer.